# Вывести все SQL запросы в рамках одной PHP транзакции

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Есть долго живущий большой проект на PHP в разработке которого в разное время принимало участие большое количество разных разработчиков. Потенциально в ходе допиливания и фикса багов могли возникнуть места в которых делаются дублирующие запросы к БД. Тоесть какой-то разработчик для решения локальной задачи мог написать и выполнить запрос возвращающий данные которые уже были ранее получены в рамках выполнения скрипта.
Сейчас на проекте встал вопрос оптимизации работы с БД в связи с чем у меня вопрос:

**Существуют ли инструменты позволяющие увидеть какие запросы к БД были сделаны в рамках одной PHP транзакции?**

Вопрос связан с тем, что точек входа в API проекта очень много и проверять все их просто читая код (который иногда весьма витиеват) займет много времени.

Comment: Да собственно General log. Не знаю, что в данном случае названо транзакцией - но идентифицировать запросы по соединениям с БД, включая время и порядок выполнения - можно. Правда, и жрёт этот лог как не в себя, так что его включать только временно, для отлова одной сессии. Ну и если используется пул соединений, то хрен там чего понять будет - соединения-то разные, даже от одного потока исполнения PHP.

Comment: Транзакцией я назвал выполнение PHP скрипта от обращения пользователя к API до выдачи ему результата запроса.
Можно ли General log включить прогмативно через PHP для конкретных проверок, а не глобально через конфиг mysql? И как отделить, в таком случае, логи записанные в рамках выполнения того скрипта где они и были активированы от других? В систему постоянно поступает большое количество внешних запросов даже в dev среде.

Comment: *как отделить, в таком случае, логи записанные в рамках выполнения того скрипта где они и были активированы от других?* В генеральском логе для каждого запроса указывается номер соединения. Он уникален - так что в рамках одного номера два клиента никогда не пересекутся. А вот один клиент несколько соединений может образовать запросто. В общем, лёгкого решения не жди... хотя если задействовать [MySQL роутер](https://www.mysql.com/products/enterprise/router.html) чисто для одного клиента и вести лог запросов там - получится чисто его, клиента, обмен.

Answer (score 0):

> Сейчас на проекте встал вопрос оптимизации работы с БД

Вывод "всех запросов" не имеет к этому вопросу **ни малейшего отношения**.

Оптимизация делается совсем по-другому. Не методом тыка пальцем в небо, а методом **профилирования**.

Начать можно со slow query log в mysql, и с оптимизации запросов из него.
Затем надо заняться профилированием скриптов, выявить узкие места и разбираться с ними. То есть, если перефразировать старый анекдот, [искать часы где потерял, а не там, где светлее](http://phpfaq.ru/humor/anecdotes#ask)

Comment: Мой вопрос не в том как оптимизировать работу с бд. А в том возможно ли прогмативно выявить дублирующиеся SQL запросы в рамках выполнения PHP скрипта.